# How to set proper output encoding in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have problem with PHP encoding.

My PHP file is UTF-8 encoded.

But every PHP function does something wrong with encoding:

For example: in my script I can write:

```
echo 'zażółć gęślą jaźń';
echo strtolower('zażółć gęślą jaźń');
```

And this is what I get:

```
zażółć gęślą jaźń
za���� g��l� ja���
```

No matter what I do or what encoding I use.

I am sure that it can be set somewhere.

`default_charset` in file *php.ini* is set to UTF-8.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtolower.php. Character conversion in that function is dependent on the locale. That site seems to have some suggested work-arounds for UTF-8 conversions.

Comment: Any php function i use changes regional letters to ? signs.

Answer (score 0):

```
$text = 'zażółć gęślą jaźń';
```

Try with `mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8');`.

Comment: No luck here. To be clear - any php function which returns a string will result in "?" signs where i have polish regional letters.

So i do not search for additional php function - but tip where to look for in php configuration

Answer (score 0):

Test this:

```
<?php
    $data = 'zażółć gęślą jaźń'

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    print json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
?>
```

OR

```
<?php
    $data = 'zażółć gęślą jaźń'

    header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8');
    print $data;
?>
```

Comment: Did not work. I think it is something in php configuration

Comment: Is this valid PHP? Isn't a semicolon missing?

Answer (score 0):

Just some input from my POV:

From my phpinfo() output on my localhost 5.5.6 for default_charset:

```
`|  Directive  Local  |  Value        |   Master Value   |
 |  default_charset   |  no value    |   no value       |`
```

*php.ini* file:

```
; By default, PHP will output a character encoding using
; the Content-type: header.  To disable sending of the charset, simply
; set it to be empty.
;
; PHP's built-in default is text/html
; http://php.net/default-mimetype
default_mimetype="text/html"

; PHP's default character set is set to empty.
; http://php.net/default-charset
;default_charset = "UTF-8"
```

Code:

```
e<?php
    $text = 'zażółć gęślą jaźń';
?>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Format using a different meta charset</title>
</head>

<body>
<?php echo mb_strtolower($text).'<br />'; ?>
<?php echo $text.'<br />'; ?>
<?php echo strtolower($text).'<br />'; ?>
<?php echo mb_strtolower('zażółć gęślą jaźń').'<br />'; ?>
<?php echo strtolower('zażółć gęślą jaźń').'<br />'; ?>
<?php echo mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8'); ?>
</body>

</html>
```

Outcome:

mb_strtolower($text) - `za���� g��l� ja��`

$text - `zażółć gęślą jaźń`

strtolower($text) - `zażółć gęślą jaźń`

mb_strtolower('zażółć gęślą jaźń') - `za���� g��l� ja��`

strtolower('zażółć gęślą jaźń') - `zażółć gęślą jaźń`

mb_strtolower($text, 'UTF-8') - `zażółć gęślą jaźń`

Comment: Your code result are:

[code]za���� g��l� ja��
zażółć gęślą jaźń
za���� g��l� ja��
za���� g��l� ja��
za���� g��l� ja��
zażółć gęślą jaźń[/code]